# How create and use a Webdriverio v6 custom reporter?

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-testing, webdriver-io

How do I create and use a Webdriverio v6 custom reporter? I do similar to this, which is what [the docs](https://webdriver.io/docs/customreporter.html) [1] seems to suggest:

[ **Edit:** I wonder if this is related to me transpiling from Typescript to Javascript. But was working fine in Webdriverio v4. ]

```
import DotReporter = require('@wdio/dot-reporter');

...

const config: WebdriverIO.Config = {
   ...

   reporters: [DotReporter],

   reporters: [  [DotReporter, {}]  ],    // this also doesn't work
```

Then this error happens:

> [0-0] 2020-04-03T23:34:22.513Z ERROR @wdio/runner: Error: Type check
>   for option "reporters" failed: **a reporter should be either a string in
>   the format "wdio--reporter" or a function/class.** Please
>   see the docs for more information on custom reporters
>   (https://webdriver.io/docs/customreporter.html) at validateConfig
>   (/project/root/node_modules/@wdio/config/build/utils.js:135:17)
>   at remote
>   (/project/root/node_modules/webdriverio/build/index.js:31:45)
>   at initialiseInstance
>   (/project/root/node_modules/@wdio/runner/build/utils.js:70:36)

But the reporter *is* a class. It's in this case Webdriver's own Dot repoter class.

Here's the source code of a reporter — Webdriverio's DotReporter — that I cannot get working, because of the above error:

```
import chalk from 'chalk'
import WDIOReporter from '@wdio/reporter'

/**
 * Initialize a new `Dot` matrix test reporter.
 */
export default class DotReporter extends WDIOReporter {
   ...
```

Please note that: `reporters: ['dot']`, although it works fine, is not a solution in this case — the reporter I actually want to use, is my own custom one. But I'm using the DotReporter in this question, because it results in the same error when I try to use it in a custom reporter way.

What do I type, to create, import and use a custom reporter?

[1] The docs: https://webdriver.io/docs/customreporter.html

Answer (score 0):

Now it works (but: "You can accept your own answer in 2 days") — I had to do two things:

1) Change from this:

```
export default class MyCustomReporter extends WDIOReporter {
```

to this:

```
export = class MyCustomReporter extends WDIOReporter {
```

(I have not tried to find out why `=` works but not `default`.)

2) Thereafter, there was this error instead:

> [0-0] 2020-04-05T01:26:30.781Z ERROR @wdio/local-runner: Failed launching test session: TypeError: Class constructor WDIOReporter cannot be invoked without 'new'

This error disappeared when I edited the Typescript compiler config file, `tsconfig.json`, to generate ES2017 Javascript code:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2017",
```

I suppose the default target is ES2015 or whatever that generates Javascript classes that Nodejs then cannot use.

Anyway, with `=` and `ES2017` the reporter now works.

Answer (score 0):

The KajMagnus answer didn't work for me but I managed to solve it anyway. In my case it looks like this (I even placed this comment here):

```
import WDIOReporter from '@wdio/reporter';

// do not try to fix next line, only this type of export works here:

module.exports = class CustomReporter extends WDIOReporter {
```

The difference is **module**.export = class; not just export = class.

In my *tsconfig.json* I use

```
"target": "ES2017",
"module": "commonjs",
"lib": [
      "es5",
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ]
```

And in wdio.conf.js

```
const CustomReporter = require('./whatever/reporter');
```

And because I use also timeline HTML screenshot reporter and spec reporter it looks like this in my case:

```
reporters: [
    [
      'timeline',
      {
        outputDir: './reports',
        embedImages: true,
        images: {
          quality: 70,
          resize: true,
          reductionRatio: 2
        },
        screenshotStrategy: 'before:click'
      }
    ],
    'spec',
    [CustomReporter, {}]
  ],
```

But if you want to use only your custom one:

```
reporters: [[CustomReporter, {}]]
```

"CustomReporter" you can replace it with whatever you like but remember to do it all over the place. Also you can choose to extend not just WDIOReporter but any other reporter you want. WDIOReporter is easy to work with because it's based on SpecReporter so I recommend it. You can do anything you want in there anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, looks like what I was actually missing was the second empty options arg in the reporters list. Turns out that's necessary, can't just do `[MyCustomReporter]`.

Answer (score 0):

This thread had help me a lot but none of the answer work.

For me to get it to work for typescript i did this

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": [
      "node",
      "@wdio/globals/types",
      "@wdio/mocha-framework"
    ],
    "target": "ES2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "es5",
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

myReporter.ts

```
import WDIOReporter from '@wdio/reporter';

export class MyReporter extends WDIOReporter {
  onTestPass(test) {
    const testJsonStr = JSON.stringify(test);
    this.write(testJsonStr);
  }
}
```

wdio.conf.ts

```
reporters: [
    'spec',
    [MyReporter, {
        outputDir: './reports/',
        outputFileFormat: () => 'output.json',
    }],
],
```